# how to do this curl operation in Node.js using request library

Tags: node.js, curl, request

How can I convert this curl operation using request Node.js library:

```
curl -L -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: authorization..." -H "Scope: 11111111" https://url/download >> file.gz

    /*the -L is curl option which means --location      Follow redirects (H)
         --location-trusted  Like '--location', and send auth to other hosts (H)*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution we have to put request inside another because: so the first request returns the url and the second one will download the file

```
const options = {
  url: url,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `auth`,
    'scope': profileId,
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
};
const r = request.get(options, async (err, res, body) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${path}.gz`);
    request(res.request.uri.href).pipe(fileStream);
    // path exists unless there was an error
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to download to a file, you can use a [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request type.

The request will look like so:

```
request.head({
    url: "https://url/download",
    followAllRedirects: true,
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':'authorization...',
    'Scope': '11111111'
  }
}, (err, res, body) => {
  request('https://url/download')
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`tmp/${res.path}`)).on('close', (data, err) => {
            if(err) console.log(`Unable to write to file ${err}`)
            console.log('Done')
    })
})
```

I have used a similar snippet which worked well

Use Postmans code generator

[image]

1. Click code on the top left
2. Paste your curl request
3. Select `Node.js Request` from dropdown on top left of popup
4. You should then get JS snippet converted from your working cURL request

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get a file which contains 401 Unauthorized. I think I need the equivalent of -L of curl option because it works perfectly with the curl command but not with the request.

Comment: Have updated my answer and added option for `followAllRedirects = true`. Give that whirl

Comment: I still got the same error the res.path returns undefined and a file which contains <title>401 Unauthorized</title>... even if as I said it works perfectly with curl

Comment: Have you got postman? You can paste your curl request in the `code` snippet generator and then select `Node.js Request` from the drop down in the top left of the popup and it should create a javascript snippet for you.

Comment: @bams I have updated my answer with a guide of how to generate the snippet via postman

Comment: Thank you, but even with postman's snippet it didn't work so strange but I found the solution which is request inside request.